# Google Sheets formula to find previous day high of a share price

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-finance

Need previous day high/low price of a share.
This formula gives answer

```
=googlefinance("nse:"&columno.,"high",today()-2.1)
```

This gives an answer with date and time in separate columns.
But I need only the value of a particular share price.
Will anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

- use **`INDEX`** to filter it out like:

  ```
  =INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:"&O18, "high", TODAY()-2.1), 2, 2)
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the answer... sir

Comment: @Arunkumar https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I need a formula for 20 moving average update every 5 minutes, i used the below formula but it show day moving average but i need live moving average change , =average(query(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2,"price",workday(today(),-21),today()-1),"select Col2"))  so kindly send me the formula

Comment: I need a formula for 20 moving average update every 5 minutes, i used the below formula but it show day moving average but i need live moving average change as (realtime)share market moves , =average(query(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2,"price",workday(today(),-21),today()-1),"select Col2")) so kindly send me the formula

Comment: Sir i need workday formula =INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:"&A2, "high", TODAY()-3.1), 2, 2)

Comment: @Arunkumar Please ask a new question instead, citing this one for reference if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
=INDEX( IF(ISNA(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2,"high",TODAY()-1))=TRUE, IF(ISNA(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2,"high",TODAY()-2))=TRUE, GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2,"high",TODAY()-3),GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2,"high",TODAY()-2)),GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2,"high",TODAY()-1)),2,2)
```

This will fetch the previous day market high.

Answer (score 0):

=INDEX( GoogleFinance( "NSE:"&A2 , "all" , TODAY()-2 ) , 2, 2) - Pre. Open

=INDEX( GoogleFinance( "NSE:"&A2 , "all" , TODAY()-2 ) , 2, 3) - Pre. High

=INDEX( GoogleFinance( "NSE:"&A2 , "all" , TODAY()-2 ) , 2, 4) - Pre. Low

=INDEX( GoogleFinance( "NSE:"&A2 , "all" , TODAY()-2 ) , 2, 6) - Pre. Volume

Answer (score 0):

knowing it that I am bit late but it may help someone else,

Try `=googlefinance("NSE:IDEA","high",WORKDAY( TODAY(), -2 ))`

- it will work for that specific date only, ie, previous day or previous day when market was opened, which ever is the case. Hope that google consider specific Stock Exchange Holiday list as well when using this particular formula though not checked that aspect.

where "NSE:IDEA" is the stock listed in NSE

Currently trying Google Finance in many possible ways as possible to get insights. If anyone wanting me to share more such formula to get specific data, please let me know and I will share. Hope you will share more and more specific formula examples to fetch specific market data based on more and more specific logical requirements to get insights on the market.